# Reference showing as a question mark despite being in the .bib file

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I'm very new to Latex so any help is appreciated. I am having trouble with some of my references. when using the `\cite{}` function some references come up as expected (e.g [1]) but others show as the question mark ([?]).

I am using TeXstudio and referencing from a single .bib. I have checked the .bib file and the reference is definitely there, I have even copied and pasted the citation key to make sure it isn't a typo error, but still I get this error. Are there any steps I can take to try and solve this?

I have already tried resynching my Mendeley library, compiling the latex document, deleting the .bib file and making a new document but none of that has worked.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Welcome. Could you please provide a small example document that has this problem. Then it is lot easier to help. Are yuo sure the citation key exists? And that you have run `bibtex`(?) and LaTeX enough times?

Comment: I have actually just found that it was a math package that was stopping this from working. I'm unsure why but the reference now shows after the package has been turned off. Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: latex doesn't read the bib file, so you need to re-run bibtex to re-generate the references and then run latex twice to resolve all references after you add any new `\cite` to the document.

Comment: This may sound very silly but I'm not sure what bibtex is or how to run it? I generated the .bib file using Mendeley and set the file up to auto sync when I created it.

Comment: You are just in luck because `TeXStudio` runs `bibtex` for you. It is the programme that converts the `.bib` data into something LaTeX can use.

Comment: Do you mind telling us which package was problematic here?

Comment: Ah okay, brilliant! And yes, the package was \usepackage{gensymb} which I was recommended for some math notation

Comment: Well `gensymb` haven't been updated since 2003 so there might be a conflict or two with other packages you are using.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll have a look for an alternate package, thank you for the help!